# How does Robert Sedgewick generate the graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Yes, I think there is a very similar question on this but there is no answer.
How did he generate the graphics in the paper outlined here 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf

Try doing this in TeX .... it seems impossible. How much code is required for that ?

update: more specific.
I want not to be able to generate the trees as outlined on page 3 and 4 of the pdf.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not that much code if you know the right tools (TikZ etc.). But please note that as it stands your question is too broad. If you specify what exactly you want to achieve and show what you've attempted this question would be better suited.

Comment: Please, tell Robert Sedgewick about `microtype`!

Comment: Hello Peter. The paper looks very nice! Maybe ask the author which packages he used in order to draw the trees?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{mred}{RGB}{178,26,52}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font = \itshape,
  % 
  node/.style = {minimum width = 1em, draw = black, circle, line width
    = 0.5pt},
  % 
  subtree/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3,
    anchor = north, draw = black, line width = 0.5pt,
    align = center, rounded corners = 6ex, outer sep = 0pt, outer sep
    = 0pt, yshift = 3em, inner sep = 1pt, text
    = mred, minimum width = 10em},
  % 
  normal edge/.style = {edge from parent/.style = {black, very thick,
      draw}},
  % 
  emph edge/.style = {edge from parent/.style = {mred, line width = 3pt,
      draw}},
  % 
  level/.style = {sibling distance = 40mm/#1^0.2}
  ]

  % tree
  \node (a) [node]{$a$}
  child[normal edge] {node[subtree] {less \\ than a}}
  child[emph edge] {node[node] (b) {b}
    child[normal edge] {node[subtree] {between \\ a and b}}
    child[normal edge] {node[subtree] {greater \\ than b}}
  };
  % labels
  \node[left = 3em, mred] (lbl h) at (a.north west){h};
  \draw[->, mred] (lbl h) -- (a);

  \node[above = 2em] (a par) at (a.north){};
  \draw[] (a par) -- (a);

  \node[right = 3em, mred, align = center] (lbl spec) at (a par.north
  east){Could be right or left, \\ red or black};
  \draw[->, mred] (lbl spec) -- (a par);

  \node[right = 3em, mred] (lbl x) at (b.north east){\bf{x}};
  \draw[->, mred] (lbl x) -- (b);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very impressive. how long does it took you to do this ? and is this new for u ?

Comment: @Peter tikz is very intuitive and creating something like this doesn't take too long. Actually building the tree is made in 5 lines of code `\node (a) ... \child [normal edge] ...` the rest of the code is just ascetics to make it look like you wanted to

Comment: how would knuth create it in TeX if he had to ? He doesn't do it in TeX, rite ? he is using another package for it.

Comment: @Peter Technically all this can be done with just pure TeX, no packages ... but is going to be painfully complicated